# add image to array angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays

**UPDATED** -- due to comments on a small error in JS

I have a simple upload program that

1. Upload image
2. Add image to array
3. Option to remove images from array
4. If happy with array save to post to API endpoint

The user will see a array populated with images already they can then remove and add new images to the array, if they are happy then progress to save the array to the API endpoint.

**Problems**

When I add image to the array preview I do not see them in the
    preview.

**My HTML**

```
    <div class="dynamic-upload-container">
        <div class="preview"><img style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{preview}}" alt="preview image"></div>
        <div class="upload-new">
            <input id="fileinput" ng-model="file" type="file" ng-model-instant="" name="file" accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this)"> {{uploadError}}
            <button ng-click="addImage()">Add image</button>
        </div>
        <div class="slots-container">
            there is a campaign {{campaign.c_name}}
            this is the max slots {{campaign.max_slots}}
            this are the slots {{campaign.slots}}
            <!--<div ng-repeat="slot in campaign.slots" class="slot"><img ng-src="{{slot.base_image}}" alt="slot image">-->

                <div ng-repeat="slot in campaign.slots"><img ng-click="addImage()" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{slot.base_image}}" alt="preview image">
                <div>this is a slot</div>
                <button ng-click="removeImage(slot)">Remove Image</button>
            </div>
             <button ng-click="SaveImage()">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

.controller('Dashboard', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

```
$scope.campaigns =[];
$scope.preview = 'img/download.png';
$scope.slots = [];
$scope.maxSlots = 5; // this dynamic

$scope.uploadImage = function () {
    // console.log('we are here');
    input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    file = input.files[0];
    size = file.size;
    if (size < 650000) {
        var fr = new FileReader;
        fr.onload = function (e) {
            var img = new Image;

            img.onload = function () {
                var width = img.width;
                var height = img.height;
                if (width == 1920 && height == 1080) {
                    $scope.preview = e.target.result;
                    $scope.perfect = "you added a image";
                    $scope.$apply();

                } else {
                    $scope.notPerfect = "incorrect definitions";
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            };
            img.src = fr.result;
        };

        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        $scope.notPerfect = "to big";
    }
};

$scope.addImage = function () {
    if ($scope.slots.length < $scope.maxSlots) {
        $scope.slots.push({
            "slot_id": $scope.slots.length + 1,
            "base_image": $scope.preview,
            "path_image": ""
        });

    } else {
        window.alert("you have to delete a slot to generate a new one");
        // console.log('you have to delete a slot to generate a new one')
    }
};

$scope.SaveImage = function () {
    $http({
        url: "http://www.site.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/updateSlots",
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'campaign': "ben", 'slots': $scope.slots },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(function (response) {
        // success
        console.log('success');
        console.log("then : " + JSON.stringify(response));
        location.href = '/cms/index.html';
    }, function (response) { // optional
        // failed
        console.log('failed');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
};

$scope.removeImage = function(s) {
    $scope.slots.splice($scope.slots.indexOf(s), 1);
};

$scope.GetData = function () {
    $http({
        url: "http://www.site.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/getCampaign",
        method: "POST",
        date: {},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(function (response) {
        // success
        console.log('you have received the data ');
        console.log(response);


        $scope.campaigns = response.data;
        //$scope.slots = data.data[0].slots;

    }, function (response) {
        // failed
        console.log(response);
    });
};

$scope.GetData();
```

})

Comment: `$scope.campaigns` is an array. It has no `$scope.campaigns.slots` property.  Did you mean `$scope.slots`? Or is `$scope.campaigns` meant to be an object?

Comment: ah that may very well be the problem, thanks

Comment: `$scope.campaigns` is defined, `$scope.slots` is defined, `$scope.campaigns.slots` is not. Undefined.

Comment: @Nich 5 seconds too late... damn

Comment: Thanks guys trying to fix this now